# Getting wrong datetime from local database using linq query, getting datetime is decreased one day from actual datetime saved in database

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite

```
await LocalDatabaseService.Instance.SqlLiteAsyncConnection.InsertOrReplaceAsync(registrationEntity)
```

This linq query is used for storing datetime in local database. There registration entity contains `DateOfBirth` as one of the fields.

Query to retrieve:

```
var registrationEntities = await LocalDatabaseService.Instance.UserTable.Where(t => t.Id == userId).ToListAsync();
```

This query gets the data based on userId. We are getting `DateOfBirth` is one day less by the actual saved `DateOfBirth` in database.

Comment: Why the SQL tag? (I see no SQL there.)

Comment: hi, I am using Linq query for getting data from database.

Comment: There  I am using sqllite service

Comment: You should always use the midnight time and not Now when counting days.  If a person was born at 8:00PM and you query the next day at 1:00PM the difference would be zero.  So with DateTime object use DateTime.Now.Date (or actual date object) which will give the time at midnight (beginning of the day).

Comment: I am using date time picker for selecting date time for user. user selected date time is saved using first linq query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use LocalDateTime or UDateTime.

Comment: Now I am using local datetime only.